# How to add checkbox inside datepicker in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, checkbox, wpf-controls

I am developing an application in WPF in .NET 3.5. I need help on how to add a check box inside the date picker. If the `CheckBox` is checked then it calculates the value of `DatePicker`.

Comment: I think you mean like the Windows Forms `DateTimePicker` control with its `ShowCheckbox` enabled to show a checkbox left to the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why add a `CheckBox` inside a `DatePicker`?  You can make something similar by using a `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0"></CheckBox>
    <DatePicker Grid.Column="1"></DatePicker>
</Grid>
```

You can even make a user control if you want to reuse the same.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good reason why you might want to do this: applications that have a mix of WPF and Winforms DateTime picker controls where there's a need for consitency (i.e., all pickers should behave/look the same). It's possible to achieve the desired behaviour either using Canvas with ZIndex or with a grid (similar to above) but by hiding the border of the DatePicker and wrapping both controls in a border.

e.g.,

```
<Border BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```